# Windows 8.1 background audio player don't work in another page in the app

Tags: c#, windows, audio, windows-8.1

I have an app that will stream audio from the internet, the media element is in the main page it works fine in it and while the app is in the background, and I have more than one page in the app, while navigation from the main page to another page the audio stops and back to work while I back to the main page.
Is there any way to make it works in the other pages in the app ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write soundboards for windows and windows phone.

Create an App wide style for the frame that contains a media element. Now the frame can play sounds, and navigating between pages will not affect the sound.

Now that the media element is on the frame, the page needs to reference that media element in some way. I create a public class to help. Then each page registers to this class to play sounds.

In the page:

```
SoundPlayer.Instance.Initialize();
```

SoundPlayer class:

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        // Register media elements to the Sound Service.
        try
        {
            DependencyObject rootGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Window.Current.Content, 0);
            var foregroundPlayer = (MediaElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootGrid, 0) as MediaElement;
            var backgroundPlayer = (MediaElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootGrid, 1) as MediaElement;

            SoundPlayer.ForegroundPlayer = foregroundPlayer;

            // Keep the state.
            var isMuted = this.IsBackgroundMuted;
            SoundPlayer.BackgroundPlayer = backgroundPlayer;
            this.IsBackgroundMuted = isMuted;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Most probably you forgot to apply the custom root frame style.
            SoundPlayer.ForegroundPlayer = null;
            SoundPlayer.BackgroundPlayer = null;
        }
    }


    public async Task Play(string soundPath, bool inBackground = false)
    {
        var mediaElement = inBackground ? BackgroundPlayer : ForegroundPlayer;

        if (mediaElement == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        mediaElement.Source = new Uri(soundPath);

        await mediaElement.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            mediaElement.Stop();
            mediaElement.Play();
        });
    }
```

In App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
                <Style x:Key="RootFrameStyle"
                       TargetType="Frame">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame">
                                <Grid>
                                    <!-- Foreground Player -->
                                    <MediaElement IsLooping="False" />
                                    <!-- Background Player -->
                                    <MediaElement IsLooping="True" />
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is a blog post that explains this in more detail.
http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/07/10/Playing-sounds-in-a-Universal-Windows-MVVM-app.aspx

Comment: I tried your sample at the linked page. Perhaps I misunderstood the "background" concept as in my WP8.1 phone your "background" sounds stop immediately when I change some other app to the foreground. Is that expected? I compiled it with VS2013 Update5